# Django DateTimeField with optional time part

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field which will represent the start time of an event and I am using the Django DateTimeField for this.
This field is mandatory but sometimes the users will only know the start date and not the time.
Is there anyway to make the time part optional and keep the date part mandatory?

Comment: You can always set time text field to _00:00_ by default.

Comment: Have you considered SplitDateTimeWidget? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#splitdatetimewidget

Comment: The dates are entered via the default admin interface which looks like it uses a SplitDateTimeWidget already - trouble is it insists on a time.  I think the answer is to do as Rohan suggests and put a midnight default.  Rohan if you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try to separate date from time. There are DateField and TimeField for that.

Comment: This would work though I was hoping not to have to create any new fields as there is data in the database already.

Answer (score 0):

Example for use at the views or models:

You can use function [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to show the datetime field any formats.

> ```
> from datetime import datetime
> datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
> # print string '2013-06-25'
> ```

Example for use at the templates:

you can use templatetag [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

> {{ datetime_field|date:"Y-m-d" }}

Comment: It is how to store the data that is the issue, not how to display it.

Comment: Ok, it same decision. Date is saved as whole  and if user must see only date you can show him as example as wrote above. If I not understood else Can you show model, form and view?

Comment: The only forms and views in use are the django default admin interface.  Client wants to enter date but not time into a DateTimeField in one of my models but this gives a validation error as time is required.   I was looking for model code to see if I could make the time non-mandatory.  It looks like this is not possible.

Comment: You can try do next steps. Firstly, at the form's class for datetime field to assign `forms.DateField`. Secondly, when saving form you have value from `form.cleaned_data['name_your_datefield']`(`form` must be instance your class form) Use it for get and to change.